# How do I get a missing agent back?

Tags: fate-of-the-world

Sometimes when unrest is high in a region, the agents I have recruited will go missing. Is there any way to get them back via certain cards, or do I need to just pay the recruitment cost again to replace them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played fotw a lot way back when it was new. I never found any way to "rescue" or "ransom" them. I think the reason they turn red when they are missing are to give you an overview of how many agents you used to have there, and so that you don't forget in what region it happened.